# Allowing switching on/off of events in EPL

Tags: java, xml, esper

Just a general question with regards to **`Esper`**. 
Does anyone know if it is possible to turn on/off EPL statements in an `EPL file` without having to comment the actual `EPL statement`.

Can it be done using `XML config file`?

If so, could you provide links to the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm an EPL file contains EPL statements and does not contain events, I guess the question is how to turn on and off EPL statements in an EPL file. Yes commenting out would work. The admin API can also be used to find statements and stop and start statements. There is also such as thing as isolated service provider that can also be used to temporarily suspend things in terms of the time and events.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I didn't know of these options in the API. I shall investigate.